# Indentation for initializer list in Constructor is wrong

Tags: c++, c++11, emacs, indentation, cc-mode

I'm using `emacs 24.3` and I've encountered the following problem with emacs indentation engine and the new `C++11` initializer lists. Let me give you an example: Consider a class `Class` which has a member of type `std::vector<int>` named `m_vector`. Emacs indents the constructor as follows:

```c++
Class() : m_vector( { 1,
            2,
            3 } ){ }
```

whereas I would expect this syntax:

```c++
Class() : m_vector( { 1,
                      2,
                      3 } ){ }
```

Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: good question. I doubt it. I also find emacs not supporting several C++11 features in the way I would like it to.

Answer (score 0):

So file a bug.

The bug tracker for GNU Emacs is here: http://debbugs.gnu.org/Emacs.html